# 504 when saving post in Wordpress (not in staging)

Tags: wordpress, nginx, timeout

I have a Wordpress installation in production that sometimes returns a 504 error when updating a post.

I have tried to clone that installation to a subdomain, in the same hosting, using the Plesk cloning tool and in the copy this problem does not occur.

Environment: PHP 7.1.26 FPM application served by Nginx (Plesk)

Any ideas about how can I solve it?

Error in Plesk log: 504 POST /wp-admin/post.php HTTP/1.1